# Why does Mathematica run amok in this Manipulate Plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

The following makes Mathematica 11.1.1.0 run amok on my system, and I have no idea why:

```
Manipulate[Plot[(p0 - \[Beta])/\[Alpha] 1/(N + 1), {N, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 10}}], {p0, 1, 10}, {\[Beta], 0, 1}, {\[Alpha], 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: For one thing, `N` is a built-in symbol. Changing it to lowercase gets me a functional plot / manipulate...

Comment: Oh, that was just a plain oversight.

Comment: Don't include 0 in the range of alpha since you don't want to divide by 0. Or just use `Quiet @ Plot[...]`